# react data grid with group by in columns

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am looking for a full feature(like editing,deleting,inserting,group by on columns,pagination and extra) data grid for reactjs.
after searching i have found react-bootstrap-table (http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/index.html) its has all of the features that i want except group by on columns. is there any other react data grid or any body knows how can i add group by in react-bootstrap-table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

It has support of grouped column

https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-columngroup-v0.5.html

Comment: not this kind of group by ... something like this http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/grouping